# Storing values of multiples columns in pyspark dataframe under a new column

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am importing data from a csv file where I have columns Reading1 and Reading2 and storing it into a pyspark dataframe.
My objective is to have a new column name Reading and its value as a array containing values of Reading1 and Reading2. How can I achieve the same in pyspark.

```
        +---+-----------+-----------+
        | id|  Reading A|  Reading B| 
        +---+-----------------------+
        |01 |  0.123    |   0.145   | 
        |02 |  0.546    |   0.756   |
        +---+-----------+-----------+

        Desired Output:
        +---+------------------+
        | id|    Reading       |
        +---+------------------+
        |01 |  [0.123, 0.145]  |
        |02 |  [0.546, 0.756   |
        +---+------------------+-
```

Comment: Use an `array` or `struct`.

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn('reading',f.array([f.col("reading a"), f.col("reading b")]))

Comment: after using this solution I am not getting any error from spark but no new columns are added to the existing df
I have also tried below but same result
df.withColumn('reading',f.array([lit(df.readingA),lit(df.readingB))

Comment: yes, the above code adds new column to existing df. you don't want that ?

Comment: The solution is working fine now. Earlier it was just returning me an empty dataframe so I posted as I it was not reflecting even when i was not getting any error.